# Unable to Connect a virtual device to Cloud IoT Core using the MQTT bridge using the command given in tutorial, "serverCertFile" missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt

I using ineractive tutorial to learn google IOT cloud.

While running below command on google cloud shell, command does not get executed says 'Missing required argument: "serverCertFile"'

node     cloudiot_mqtt_example_nodejs.js     mqttDeviceDemo     --cloudRegion=us-central1     --proj
ectId=nth-setup-305706     --registryId=my-registry     --deviceId=my-node-device     --privateKeyFile=../rsa_private.pem     --numMessages=25     --algorithm=RS256     --mq
ttBridgePort=443

Added --serverCertFile=../rsa_cert.pem  , that does not help

Thanks For The support in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cert file you're missing is (I believe) the Google root certificate file. You can get it with wget or curl:

`wget https://pki.google.com/roots.pem`

Then pass that to the `--serverCertFile` flag.

Comment: Thank You!! this helped. I was able to complete all the steps in interactive tutorials.

Comment: This step is missing in interactive tutorials, tutorials should be fixed

Comment: Do you have links for which tutorials? I can take a look. I include it in my blog post here: https://medium.com/GabeWeiss/cloud-iot-step-by-step-cloud-to-device-communication-655a92d548ca

Comment: Cloud interactive tutorials, I have informed the team via github(I had raised an issue in github) -  https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?tutorial=iot_core_quickstart    Thank you for your tutorial link...